# How to specify the GCP Credential Location in application.properties file (for using the Pub/Sub in GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, credentials

This seems straightforward to do that passing the Service Account key file (generated from the GCP console) by specifying the file location in the application.properties file. However, I tried all the following options:

```
1. spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/home/my_user_id/mp6key.json
2. spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/mp6key.json
3. spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:./main/resources/mp6key.json
4. spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/src/main/resources/mp6key.json
```

It all ended up with the same error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/my_user_id/mp6key.json (No such file or directory)
```

Could anyone advise where I should put the key file and then how should I specify the path to the file properly?

The same programs run successfully in Ecplise with messages published and subscribed using the Pub/Sub processing from GCP (using the Project Id/Service Account key generated in GCP), but now stuck with the above issue after deployed to run on GCP.

Comment: Is the application which use the service account key file will run on GCP? Just to be sure, your last sentence seems to say yes to this question.

Comment: Yes. the same application ran successfully in Eclipse, then deployed to run on GCP but failed with the above problem.

Comment: Have you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem. It works with the the environment variable, but not with my application properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-java)? Please, try to follow it thoughtfully and explain if you get any error finishing the quickstart.

Anyway, before running your Java script, try running on the console the following (please modify with the exact path where you store your key):

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/mp6key.json"
```

How are you authenticating your credentials in your Java script?

Comment: I tried GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and now it failed with error:    

PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.     
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.       

It's not a JS, instead it's a Java Spring service program which uses @MessagingGateway for sending a message.

Guess I will have to migrate the logic to follow exactly the same the way from the quickstart.

Comment: @RoyHu You have to add the Secret Manager permission to your default App Engine Service Account.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/spring-cloud-gcp-core.html#_credentials), the credentials file can be obtained from a number of different locations such as the file system, classpath, URL, etc.

for example, if the service account key file is stored in the classpath as `src/main/resources/key.json`, pass the following property

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:key.json
```

if the key file is stored somewhere else in your local file system, use the `file` prefix in the property value

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:<path to key file>
```

Answer (score 2):

My line looks like this:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/[my_json_file]
```

And this works.

The following also works if I put it in the root of the project directory:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:./[my_json_file]
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is easy: if you run you code on GCP, you don't have to use service account key file. Problem eliminated, problem solved!

More seriously, have a look on service identity. I don't know what is your current service (Compute? Function? Cloud Run?). Anyway, you can attach any service account on GCP components. Then, when you code, simply use the default credential. Automatically the component identity is loaded. **No key to manage, no key to store securely, no key to rotate!**

If you provide more detail on your target platform, I could provide your some guidance to achieve this.

Keep in mind that the service account key file are designed to **be used by automatic apps (w/o user account involved) hosted outside GCP** (on prem, other Cloud Provider, a CI/CD, Apigee,...)

**UPDATE**

When you use your personal account, you can also use the default credential.

- Install `gcloud SDK` on your computer
- Use the command `gcloud auth application-default login`
- Follow the instructions
- Enjoy!

If it doesn't work, get the `<path>` displayed after the login command and set this value in the environment variable named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

If you definitively want to use service account key file (which are a security issue for the previous reason, but...), you can use it locally

- Either set the json key file path into the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable
- Or run this command `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<path to your json key file>`

Comment: The reason I'm using a service account/key is because I'm trying to deploy the same program tested working well in Eclipse (where it runs out of GCP therefore need the account to access the GCP Pub/Sub).

I will try not to use the account/key after I migrate the logic to follow exactly the same as the quickstart.

Comment: What is "Eclipse" for you? The IDE? on your local environment?

Comment: yes Eclipse IDE, there the program was tested in localhost of my laptop

Comment: Ok I updated my recommendation in bold, and I adding how to perform in your local environment with your user account.

Comment: Thanks for update!. My case is the program working well in my local envrionment. The problem is the same program not working with Google Kubetetes Engine on GCP due to insufficient authentication scopes.

Comment: my issues is not relevant to this topic anymore, so I closed this and raised another one

Answer (score 1):

For Pub/Sub credentials using Spring Cloud, use this property.

`spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.credentials.location=file:/someLocation/keyFileName.json`

Answer (score 0):

Provided your file is in the resources folder try

`file://mp6key.json`

using `file://` instead of `file:/` works for me at least

Answer (score 0):

in my Spring `appplication-test.yaml` I put

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      sql:
        enabled: false
      credentials:
        location: classpath:dummy-gcloud-credentials.json
```

and in `service/src/test/resources/dummy-gcloud-credentials.json` I put

```
{
  "client_id": "dummy-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "dummy-secret",
  "refresh_token": "dummy-token",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

and the problem was gone for some tests using the Spring "test" profile.
I don't remember however if the tests stopped there or just logged the error.

The same fix helped me with this error below logged during the start of some tests using the Spring "test" profile. In that case, the "error" was logged but did not block the test execution.

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.`

Comment: The question was not about a test environment, but this is exactly what I was looking for.